# Scala - Is it a bad practice to explicitly use Future failure in for comprehension for validation

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I sometimes find myself doing verifications and use Future.failed in for comprehension with Futures. I find it very useful but on the other hand I've never seen this technique in other's people code.

Example:

```
  for {
  user <- db.getUsers("Mark")
  doesNotExist <- Future.failed(UserDoesNotExistsException("Mark")) if user.size < 0
  userProducts <- db.getUsersProducts(user)
} yield usersProducts
```

then the clients can match Failure and know exactly which step failed.

Is code like this not a good practice?

Comment: It really depends on your domain, but most of the time this type of validations should be done in the retrieving functions themselves. In your case, for example, I would move the size validation to the `getUsersProducts` function.

Comment: Thanks! Good idea